# How to disable javascript debugging on Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I'm getting crazy with the VS2008 javascript debugging. Every time I run my web application (mvc) it starts to debug everything. I don't want it! I didn't find any option for that and I already disabled js debugging on IE.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [the answer you are looking](http://pagebrooks.com/archive/2008/04/23/easily-disable-javascript-debugging-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx) for is here. You didn't find it because the solution is inside IE not VS.

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: You beat me with the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

See the following page: http://pagebrooks.com/archive/2008/04/23/easily-disable-javascript-debugging-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx

> Quote:
>   You can toggle these settings in your Internet Explorer settings

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't work in win7. He needs to update his pages

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you haven't placed any breakpoint on javascript statements.